# How to use the rigid body method at Unity 5.1.2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class RigidBodyScript : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            this.transform.rigidbody.AddForce() (
                Vector3.forward * 300 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I read a book and try to use the transform.rigidbody.AddForce() method.
But the unity version of book is previous, so at my unity program that method make error at rigid body.
At Unity 5.1.2, how to use this method?

Comment: You've put in too many brackets... This code would never compile. It should be `this.transform.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.forward * 300 * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: The unity say "Some scripts have compilation errors which may prevent obsolete API usages to get updated. Obsolete API updating will continue automatically after these error get fixed.

Comment: @T.Kiley Oh I miss that. But that code make error.

Comment: @LokiSinclair Unity say the "API updating failed. Check previous console messages.". So I check the console messages,

Comment: Internal error: Recursion detected while updating scripts(assembly index:4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rigidbody` property is [deprecated in recent versions of Unity](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/23/unity5-api-changes-automatic-script-updating/). So accessing them with a `transform.rigibody` won't work any more.

You will have to get the Rigidbody component with a `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` call now (or one of the other GetComponent varieties).

This is what Unity is trying to correct for you. It can't however, given that the code you have written won't compile in the first place. For example

```
this.transform.rigidbody.AddForce() (Vector3.forward * 300 * Time.deltaTime);
```

contains too many braces.

So that is what it's telling you: "I'm trying to upgrade your code, but I can't".

Comment: I use that method, so Unity doesn't make error. But methods do not work... Press the up arrow, but nothing.

Comment: You can't be using it, because it doesn't compile. Otherwise you wouldn't get the errors. So if you are using something, show us the actual code that is running.

Comment: My code is, this.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (Vector3.forward * 13000 * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: And the rest of your Rigidbody component setup looks like ...?

Comment: What is the Rigidbody component setup??

Comment: Mass, drag, angular drag, use gravity, etc. The settings of your rigid body. And you did verify your code gets called upon a key press?

Comment: 1, 0.5, 0.05, check, none, None, Discrete, none, none. Oh I miss that!!! I do that right now!!!!

Comment: Wow... You are right. The IF sentence doesn't work. But at the other code, that sentence was worked.

Comment: Oh my god.... I did a big mistake. I drag the other code to object. Oh no........ That code is working now!! Thanks to your grate and wholehearted answer!!!!!!!

Comment: Haha, ah well, glad you fixed it. :)